# Wirecloud /Fi-ware widget Include an html in the widget settings

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Is it possible to include an html document in the widget settings?
So I got a few options to choose from, but the the amount isn't always the same.

So I need a possibility to dynamically edit the settings window.
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, as the standard preferences mechanism uses the manifest xml file. So the preferences are handled outside your widget code.

You can always create your own settings button and settings display inside your widget-window.

Comment: I feared that this isn't possible.
They should take that on the to-do list. In my opinion this would be a very useful thing.